# Spark-etl load data into accumulo failure

Tags: accumulo, geotrellis

When I learned to use **geotrellis** to load data into **accumulo**, I had a problem:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   geotrellis.spark.io.package$LayerWriteError: Failed to write
>   Layer(name = "example", zoom = 13)......
>   rg.apache.accumulo.core.client.AccumuloException:
>   file:/geotrellis-ingest/726314aa-5b72-4f9c-9c41-f9521a045603-O45VGIHPpi:
>   java.io.IOException:
>   file:/geotrellis-ingest/726314aa-5b72-4f9c-9c41-f9521a045603-O45VGIHPpi
>   is not in a volume configured for Accumulo

Here are images of my config file:
[config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNzaH.png)

[config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NRdC.png)

[config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fO7mV.png)

Comment: I've edited your post a little to help make it a little more readable.  Setting aside the error into a quote, and fixing a couple of words.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with geotrellis or spark, but the error message indicates that there's a [bulk import](https://accumulo.apache.org/1.9/accumulo_user_manual.html#_bulk_ingest) into Accumulo being attempted across [filesystems (volumes)](https://accumulo.apache.org/1.9/accumulo_user_manual.html#_multi_volume_installations), which Accumulo doesn't support.

The files you bulk import must be on a volume that is already configured for use in Accumulo. Accumulo will move the files within the same volume to its own directories, but it won't move them across volumes. To configure volumes for use within Accumulo, see the documentation for [instance.volumes](https://accumulo.apache.org/1.9/accumulo_user_manual.html#_instance_volumes).